# Struts2 using Map in select tag

Tags: struts2

You can easily use a List in struts2 select tag, but is there a way to use Map in  tag?? If it is possible please provide a sample code...

thanx !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my action class

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
   private Map<String, String> map;

   public String execute() throws Exception {
       map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       map.put("abc", "abc");
       map.put("xyz", "xyz");
       return SUCCESS;
   }
}
```

For the jsp mapped to success, use some thing like this

```
<s:select list = "map" name = "name" label = "Name" headerKey="" headerValue = "Enter Value"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what are you trying to do. Lacking details, I can only point you to the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/select.html) : the `list` attribute of the `select` tag is an ...

> Iterable source to populate from. If
>   the list is a Map (key, value), the
>   Map key will become the option 'value'
>   parameter and the Map value will
>   become the option body.

Below in the same doc there is an example with a (literal, inline) map (Months).

Comment: Leonboy's suggestion is optimal if you have literal values to add to a list. How are you generating the list? Do you have a map that you are trying to load? In that case you can pass the action variable referencing the map to the "list" attribute. Look at my answer for that example.