# how to display value to the select tag in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

How to display value to the select tag in struts2, I am using list of values as Map

My code

first type:

action class,

```
private Map<Integer, String> mapForSelect;

    mapForSelect.put(1, "map 1");
    mapForSelect.put(2, "map 2");
    mapForSelect.put(3, "map 3");
    mapForSelect.put(4, "map 4");
    mapForSelect.put(5, "map 5");
    mapForSelect.put(6, "map 6");
      ..........
         .........

settres and getters for "mapForSelect"
```

jsp page,

```
<s:select label="Map Demo" list="mapForSelect" value= "3" />
```

It will show select default value as "map 3"

second type:

```
private Map<String, String> mapForSelect;

    mapForSelect.put("one", "map 1");
    mapForSelect.put("second", "map 2");
    mapForSelect.put("three", "map 3");
    mapForSelect.put("four", "map 4");
    mapForSelect.put("five", "map 5");
    mapForSelect.put("six", "map 6");
      ..........
         .........

settres and getters for "mapForSelect"
```

jsp page,

```
<s:select label="Map Demo" list="mapForSelect" value= "three" />
```

This time that select doesn't show any default value, I want to this way to show default value.

please give solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887316/struts2-using-map-in-select-tag

Comment: @MichaelFreake Not really--OP already knows *how* to use a map, but isn't able to pre-load the value. Linked question asks something else, and doesn't address setting the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `value="'three'"` instead so the value will be a string.